# Android Native Browser duplicating HTML5 canvas (fine in chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas

This is a weird issue that I am only experiencing on a Native browser on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and Galaxy S2 in the native browser.

This has also been tested on other android phones and tablets such as the Nexus 7 & Galaxy S4 but their native browser is chrome, so it appears fine. This issue is also not present on any IOS browsers, Windows Desktop browsers or Mac Desktop browsers.

It's almost asif the webpage is loaded twice ontop of itself!

As there is a duplicate canvas element, that updates as the main canvas does.

[image]
[image]

Here it appears asthough it only happens when rotated in landscape mode, but I beleive that in portrait mode, the canvas' are perfectly aligned over the top.

What is even weirder, the menu button that you see is a toggle button, tap to open menu, tap to close menu. On this device when you tap it, it opens and closes instantly. the same happens for the mute button toggle.

I'm completely at a loss.

I have done some javascript debugging throwing in a few alerts here and there, and the initialisation functions that create references to the canvas and so on are only called once.

I have read and heard about hardware acceleration causing issues, but solutions i've potentially found are only relative to building native apps! not HTML5 Canvas webpages.

Any insight on this could be would be great!
Thanks in advance.

--EDIT

I also put in this test `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').length);` to see if there was 2 canvas in the DOM but it returns 1!

Comment: What about Checking the useragent of your Samsung then remove the second one. I am confused if this possible since length is 1 of canvas tag.

Comment: Please try to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the problem, then we can see the source and try on other devices.

Comment: @Pool Right, Since everyone don't have the samsung device do you have any trick in mind. I tried last time IOS simulator in Win7 through Webmatrix and it's failed to show me bug similar to the problem found in this question.

Comment: It isn't just to reproduce the issue, reducing the problem to a small test case also may help isolate the issue for RoryPicko92, or show some uncommon or incorrect usage that might cause some glitches.

Comment: @Pool i created a SSCCE version and it was bug free! so i started added little functionality at a time, and I've narrowed it down to canvas scaling (with css) or the fact it is being positioned in the center of the screen using css left, here is the SSCCE version http://kokodev.co.uk/canvasbug/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this same issue. I was able to fix this by running the following code after making a change to my canvas:

```
// If Samsung android browser is detected
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('534.30') > 0) {

    // Tweak the canvas opacity, causing it to redraw
    $('canvas').css('opacity', '0.99');

    // Set the canvas opacity back to normal after 5ms
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('canvas').css('opacity', '1');
    }, 5);

}
```

By tweaking the opacity, this forced the canvas to redraw and removed the duplicate shapes. It's a dumb fix but it works. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This doesnt fix the issue for me, the canvas is still duplicated. Also there is already a setTimeout running an update funcation 30 times a second that redraws the entire canvas.

Comment: Try putting this code at the bottom of your setTimeout update function.

Comment: thanks! this does work! the only problem is that it now runs even slower on these old devices. Oh well! shame there isn't a nicer work around though as i'm only building a really simple menu based game now and it slows it down dramatically (not that performance was great on this device anyway)!

Comment: After more testing I came up with these results...
The opacity hack forces the 'fake' canvas to update, so it's still there, but theyre identically overlayed so it goes un notices. BUT the fake canvas doesnt take into account the positioning of the canvas with css properties margin, translate, or top/left. so the fake canvas is updating but its offset from the real canvas. Still not fully fixed it! :(

Comment: Wrapping the canvas in a div that is the same size and applying the css positional properties to that instead seems to stop the 'fake' canvas offset.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may look at this collections of such tips: http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/

Answer (score 1):

For double canvas issue there is a bug logged https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474 you may want to check suggested solutions.

In my case this issue appeared only if I had Force GPU rendering enabled.

Issue usually appears if you have some parent element for canvas that has CSS `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

remove overflow property from all canvas parents,probably we don’t need this property on touch devices:

```
$("canvas").parents("*").css("overflow", "visible");
```

It is well explained at http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/